# Skip GitHub action on file/directory delete

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, gitlab-ci, devops, cicd

I would like to skip/exclude my GitHub actions (for example copyright) only on deleted files/directory while raising pull request.
how can i do it ?

I trying this :

```
on:
  pull_request_target:
    lables:
      types: !deleted

jobs:
  update-copyright:
```

but not sure if its correct way of doing it.

Comment: You can't identify this event using the `on` configuration alone. A workaround could be to always run your workflow, using a `setup` job that would run first to check if some file/folder has been deleted, generating an `output` that would be used to run or not a sequential `copyright` job.